# Adding custom ticks/labels to x-axies

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization, ticks, charts

I have the following plot:

[image]

Generated using the following code:

```
zmin=10;
zmax=100;
d=5;
gridpoints=Subdivide[Log[zmin],Log[zmax],d]
breakpoints=Map[Exp,gridpoints]
fpoints=Map[Log,breakpoints]
Show[{Plot[Log[x],{x,0,110},Ticks->None],
Graphics[{Dashed,Map[Line,Thread[{Thread[{breakpoints,ConstantArray[0,d+1]}],
Thread[{breakpoints,fpoints}]}]]}],
Graphics[{Dashed,Map[Line,Thread[{Thread[{ConstantArray[0,d+1],gridpoints}],
Thread[{breakpoints,fpoints}]}]]}]}]
```

I would like to add labels "x_0" "x_1" ... "x_6" to where the vertical dashed lines meet the x-axis.

How can I implement such custom tick labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code could be streamlined but I have left it as is. Using existing code just make this change:

```
Plot[Log[x], {x, 0, 110}, 
 Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{#1, "x_" <> ToString[First[#2] - 1]} &, 
    Thread[{breakpoints, ConstantArray[0, d + 1]}][[All, 1]]], None}]
```

[image]